# How i can add multiple input field dynamically

Tags: visualforce

How i can add multiple input field dynamically and how we can send multiple input field data to controller. 
Example:

```
<apex:page controller="controllermethod">
 <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock mode="edit"><br/><br/>
        <div class="row">
       <apex:outputLabel styleClass="label" value="Project Name " /> 
       <apex:inputField styleClass="field" value="{!newproj.Name}"/>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
       <apex:outputLabel styleClass="label" value="Start Date "/> 
       <apex:inputField styleClass="field" value="{!newproj.Start_Date__c}"/>
        </div>
      <div class="row">
       <apex:outputLabel styleClass="label" value="Module "/> 
       <apex:inputField styleClass="field" value="{!module.Name}"/>
       </div> 
       <div class="row">
       <apex:outputLabel styleClass="label" value="Vendor "/> 
       <apex:inputField styleClass="field" value="{!module.Vendor__c}"/>
       </div> 
       <div class="row">
       <apex:outputLabel styleClass="label" value="Module "/> 
       <apex:inputField styleClass="field" value="{!module.Name}"/>
       </div> 
       <div class="row">
       <apex:outputLabel styleClass="label" value="Vendor "/> 
       <apex:inputField styleClass="field" value="{!module.Vendor__c}"/>
       </div> 
     <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!savecreatenew}"/>
      <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!closePopup}" />
      </apex:pageBlock>   
        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My controller is:-

```
public class controllermethod 
{
public  Project__c newproj{get;set;}
   public Module__c  module{get;set;}

    public controllermethod()
    {
         newproj = new Project__c();
         module=new Module__c();
    }
 public PageReference savecreatenew() {
    insert  newproj; 
    module.Project__c = String.valueOf(newproj.get('Id'));
     insert  module; 
    module.clear();
    newproj = new Project__c();
        return null;
    }

}
```

This is working fine but i want to add multiple modules for single project i.e i want to provide one add button for users to add multiple modules and vendors for that project.

Answer (score 5):

if we want to create a row dynamically, we  just need to create instance and add to the list, and use the list in vf page like below

add one more button  as add

```
<apex:commandButton value="Add" action="{!Add}"/>
```

and the apex class is like below

```
public class controllermethod {

    public Project__c newproj {get;set;}
    public List<Module__c>  moduleList {get;set;}

    public void Add() {
        Module__c module=new Module__c();
        moduleList.add(module);
    }

    public controllermethod() {
        newproj = new Project__c();
        Module__c module = new Module__c();
        moduleList.add(module);
    }

    public PageReference savecreatenew() {
        insert newproj; 
        for (Module__c module :moduleList) {
            module.Project__c = String.valueOf(newproj.get('Id'));
        } 
        insert moduleList; 
        module.clear();
        return null;
    }
}
```

VF page is like below

```
<apex:page controller="controllermethod">
```

```
  <apex:repeat value="moduleList" var="module">
  <div class="row">
   <apex:outputLabel styleClass="label" value="Module "/> 
   <apex:inputField styleClass="field" value="{!module.Name}"/>
   </div> 
   <div class="row">
   <apex:outputLabel styleClass="label" value="Vendor "/> 
   <apex:inputField styleClass="field" value="{!module.Vendor__c}"/>
   </div> 
   <div class="row">
   <apex:outputLabel styleClass="label" value="Module "/> 
   <apex:inputField styleClass="field" value="{!module.Name}"/>
   </div> 
   <div class="row">
   <apex:outputLabel styleClass="label" value="Vendor "/> 
   <apex:inputField styleClass="field" value="{!module.Vendor__c}"/>
   </div> 
  </apex:repeat> 
 <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!savecreatenew}"/>
  <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!closePopup}" />
  </apex:pageBlock>   
  </apex:form></apex:page>
```

If you want to use delete row , you need to give indexing to each row added for that , we need to use wrapper class like below

```
public class indexwrapper {
    integer rowIndex;
    Module__c module;
}
```

Use this wrapper class list instead of the `Module__c` list, when you want to delete  just pass the row index using `<apex:actionFunction/>` and delete the row.

Comment: this is working fine but my form is popup form and it will display after clicking on button.Now my problem is after calling add method of controller class vf page getting refresh and popup will disappear.

Comment: Hi all! I have some pages using this kind of solution, but now I'm getting troubles with lookup fields. When an item is removed from the list, the values of the lookup fields get crazy! Ie. After inserting 3 items and deleting the first one, If you try to submitt the form by using the save button, all the values from lookup disapear and the others fields stay with the same value. Have you guys got on this issue too? Thanks.